# Django test client does not provide the right authentication headers

Tags: django, authentication

When sending a request to the development server, I can include a header as follows:

```
Authorization: Token efc7fa291f4e320ff4a31cf9a11d6de3a366937cd1ec24e0a7ab68dafa38430f\r\n
```

Internally Django sees an `HTTP_AUTHORIZATION` header, which I am not sure where is generated.

But when using the Django test client for unit testing:

```
from django.test import Client

c = Client()
response = c.get('/api/auth/user/', **{'Authorization': 'Token ' + token})
```

Django can not authorize the request.

If instead I do the following:

```
response = c.get('/api/auth/user/', **{'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION': 'Token ' + token})
```

It works.

I would like to understand what is going on.

Who is responsible of performing the mapping `Authorization` -> `HTTP_AUTHORIZATION`?

Relevant for this question: I am using `Django 2.1.5`, `djangorestframework = "==3.9.0"` and `djangorestframework = "==3.9.0"`

Answer (score 4):

This is what the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/testing/tools/#making-requests) says:

> The headers sent via `**extra` should follow CGI specification. For example, emulating a different “Host” header as sent in the HTTP request from the browser to the server should be passed as HTTP_HOST.

And here's the relevant CGI quote:

> HTTP_* :
>
> These variables are specific to requests made with HTTP.
>         Interpretation of these variables may depend on the value of
>         SERVER_PROTOCOL.
>
> Environment variables with names beginning with "HTTP_" contain
>         header data read from the client, if the protocol used was HTTP.
>         The HTTP header name is converted to upper case, has all
>         occurrences of "-" replaced with "*" and has "HTTP*" prepended to
>         give the environment variable name. The header data may be
>         presented as sent by the client, or may be rewritten in ways which
>         do not change its semantics. If multiple headers with the same
>         field-name are received then they must be rewritten as a single
>         header having the same semantics. Similarly, a header that is
>         received on more than one line must be merged onto a single line.
>         The server must, if necessary, change the representation of the
>         data (for example, the character set) to be appropriate for a CGI
>         environment variable.

This is what Django sees, since all your requests are processed by a CGI-compatible app server (WSGI actually, gunicorn and uwsgi for example). So basically the test client wants a CGI request, which means your have to convert the HTTP headers according to the rules above.